# Is `respond_to_missing?`'s second argument useful for anything?

Tags: ruby

When using [`method_missing`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing) in Ruby, it's [almost always a good idea](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/always-define-respond-to-missing-when-overriding) to define [`respond_to_missing?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-respond_to_missing-3F) as well.

[`respond_to_missing?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-respond_to_missing-3F) takes two arguments; the name of the method we're checking (`symbol`), and a boolean which indicates whether we should include private methods in our check (`include_all`).

Now here's what I'm confused about: [`method_missing`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing) doesn't take any arguments which might indicate to it whether it should call private methods or not, as [`respond_to_missing?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-respond_to_missing-3F) does. Furthermore, [`method_missing`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing) gets called regardless of whether the original method call was in a public or private context, and regardless of what [`respond_to_missing?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-respond_to_missing-3F) returns for the given method in the appropriate context. So all operations of [`method_missing`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing) are accessible publicly.

If that's the case, then what purpose does the second argument to [`respond_to_missing?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-respond_to_missing-3F) (`include_all`) serve? Whether the given object responds to a missing method **cannot** be affected by the context in which the missing method was called, so why even have this argument at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that `respond_to_missing?` has a second argument for the same reason that [`respond_to?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F) does.  In both cases, it allows code to ask an object what methods it responds to in a way that respects method privacy.  If used properly, it can help you encapsulate your objects better.

You have pointed out a missing feature in `method_missing`, namely that it should have an argument that says whether the method was called in a public or private context.  Maybe `method_missing` will have that feature some day.  Until then, all functionality of the object that is implemented through `method_missing` will effectively be public, but you can still discourage people from using it in your documentation and via `respond_to_missing?`.

Comment: Hmm... so you're saying that even though there currently is no way to make a missing method private, you could use `respond_to_missing?` to partially imitate that behavior by not advertising the existence of missing methods that you might want to be private?

Answer (score 0):

> method_missing doesn't take any arguments which might indicate to it
>   whether it should call private methods or not

method_missing() does not call public or private methods.  method_missing() is called at the very end of the method lookup path when a method cannot be found.  So comparing method_missing() and respond_to* is non-sensical.  Why do you think that they have to operate the same way?  respond_to?() never was symmetrical with method_missing() in the first place.

Comment: "method_missing() does not call public or private methods" Well, it could. My point is that method missing can be used to simulate the existence of "methods" which don't actually exist. These "methods", **must** be public, due to the fact that `method_missing` has no knowledge of the public/private context in which the missing "method" is being called. Therefore, since all missing "methods" are public, why would it make sense for `respond_to_missing?` to have a second argument which allows it to return different values depending on whether we're looking for "private" or "public" "methods"?

Comment: Note the quotes: When I say "method", I mean the non-existent method which `method_missing` is simulating the existence of.