# What does "include_all" means in respond_to_missing?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

It's a [good rule of thumb](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/always-define-respond-to-missing-when-overriding) to define `respond_to_missing?` for a class when overriding `method_missing`.

I see, however, that [respond_to_missing?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F) accepts 2 arguments: the method name and `include_all`. I was trying to find an explanation of what the second argument actually means (and why is it set to false), but couldn't find anything. Even the documentation doesn't mention it. I've tried playing around with the method to see if the argument has some implications of the return value, but couldn't find any. Can someone please explain why does `include_all` exists at all?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213235/is-respond-to-missings-second-argument-useful-for-anything

Comment: That answer is very bad, as outlined by the answer after it.

Answer (score 0):

From [this post's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213235/is-respond-to-missings-second-argument-useful-for-anything) comment:

> Hmm... so you're saying that even though there currently is no way to make a missing method private, you could use respond_to_missing? to partially imitate that behavior by not advertising the existence of missing methods that you might want to be private?

If you call a method `respond_to?(:might_be_private_method, true)`, then in your method `respond_to_missing?(method_name, include_all)` you would get `include_all` as `true`, from which you could further mimic the method scoping.

I don't think there is any other special behaviour.